# Iterate directories in SQL Server 2012/2014

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, foreach-loop-container, ssdt-bi

We have been using a custom component for iterating directories in SQL Server 2008 R2. Now, we are planning to upgrade to SQL Server 2014, but it looks like SQL Server 2014 does not support custom components from 2008 R2 (not quite sure what's going on). Does anyone know of any other way to iterate directories?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this isn't a direct answer to your question, but it does address your underlying problem of not being able to use your 2008 component in 2014.

According to MSDN docn for SQL Server 2014 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280546(v=sql.120).aspx

> You can use the current release of SQL Server Integration Services
>   tools to run and manage packages that include SQL Server 2008 and SQL
>   Server 2008 R2 SSIS custom components. We added four binding
>   redirection rules to the following files to help redirect the runtime
>   assemblies from version 10.0.0.0 (SQL Server 2008 R2) to version
>   11.0.0.0 (SQL Server 2014).
>
> ```
> DTExec.exe.config
>
> dtshost.exe.config
>
> DTSWizard.exe.config
>
> DTUtil.exe.config
>
> DTExecUI.exe.config
> ```
>
> To use SQL Server Data Tools to design packages that include SQL
>   Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 custom components, you need to
>   modify the devenv.exe.config file that is located at :\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE.
>
> To use these packages with customer applications that are built with
>   the runtime for SQL Server 2014, include redirection rules in the
>   configuration section of the *.exe.config file for the executable. The
>   rules redirect the runtime assemblies to version 11.0.0.0 (SQL Server
>   2014). For more information about assembly version redirection, see
>    Element for `<runtime>`.

BTW there is more information on the webpage

Comment: Thank you! But I tried this using information here- https://svenaelterman.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/using-ssis-2008-components-in-sql-server-data-tools-with-ssis-2012/#comment-5926 . But SSDT fails to open after these changes, it gives out this error - Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration’ or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.